# Sitecore 10 Content Serialization With Visual Studio

Tags: serialization

I am working on Sitecore 10 content serialization and I am using `Sitecore for Visual Studio`. I am following this document:

https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/developer-tools/install-sitecore-for-visual-studio.html

Below steps I have done:

1. Install `Sitecore Management Services`.
2. Downloaded `Sitecore for Visual Studio 1.0.0.4`

When I am trying to run Visual Studio installer `SVS.VSIX.vsix`, it is throwing the below error:

[image]

***Log***

```
13-07-2021 09:44:58 - Signature Details...
13-07-2021 09:44:58 -   Extension is signed with a valid signature.
13-07-2021 09:44:58 - 
13-07-2021 09:44:58 - Searching for applicable products...
13-07-2021 09:44:58 - Found installed product - Global Location
13-07-2021 09:44:58 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Professional 2017
13-07-2021 09:44:58 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
 at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
 at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
 at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
 at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
 at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
 at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

I am using `Visual Studio 2017`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I can't find this listed anywhere in the documentation, Visual Studio 2017 is not supported for this Visual Studio Plugin.

If you rename the downloaded VSIX file to `.zip` and open it, inside you will find the `extension.manifest` file. This is an XML file that describes what the plugin will install to.

```
  <Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[16.0,17.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
  </Prerequisites>
```

As seen here, it supports Visual Studio release 16 and 17. Your version - Visual Studio 2017 - is [release 15](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes).

You need to get on Visual Studio 2019 or higher to use this plugin.

You *could* try and edit this manifest to allow it to install on your version of Visual Studio. Needless to say this would be unsupported territory and I have no idea if it will work or not.

Comment: Thanks, Mark for your input but it is not working

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I tried to update Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor version instead of upgrade Visual Studio 2017 to 2019

Comment: Yea. Well that detail is important. You will need to upgrade VS - as also stated in the answer. There is no other "input" to be had.